# how can i make the scrollbar thumb stay inside the scrollbox?

Tags: html, css

working with a scrollbox that has uneven borders, everythings going good but i cant seem to figure out how to make the thumb stay inside the borders, ive tried working with the z index already. i wanted to change the thumb to a custom image as well but i think i should work on this bit first. this is the full code, apologies if its a bit funky as im still a beginner to coding.

i already checked some other posts on here as well but i couldnt really find anything that worked. any advice is appreciated!

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: gothicpixel;
  src: url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/69gsw1ubmz94bh2/DoubleHomicide.ttf);
}

#cont {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/657655298613575691/853068735812206612/lace-border-png-37013.png") 60 fill round;
  border-radius: 0px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  filter: drop-shadow(.7px .5px 1px white) drop-shadow(.7px .5px 1px white);
}

.imgbg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

#float {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: gothicpixel;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: regular;
  color: #aa0000;
  text-shadow: -.9px 0 #fff, 0 .9px #fff, .9px 0 #fff, 0 -.9px #fff, 0 0;
  animation-name: floating;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes floating {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0, 15px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -0px);
  }
}

#scroll {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 4%;
  width: 250px;
  top: 140px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 255px 15px 225px 15px/15px 225px 15px 255px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: #FFFFFF90;
  transition: opacity .35s ease;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: wow;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 255px 15px 225px 15px/15px 225px 15px 255px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 255px 15px 225px 15px/15px 225px 15px 255px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #aa0000;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#cont:hover #scroll {
  opacity: 1;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 35%, black 165%);
}

#cont:hover #overlay {
  width: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 1%, black 199%, black 150%, black 100%, black 75%, black 50%, black 25%, gray 200%);
  transition: background 4s ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">

  <img class=imgbg src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/940072943424270426/994052217600487524/mana_birra.jpg">
  <div id="float"> tomy </div>
  <div id="overlay"> </div>
  <div id="scroll"> hi this is <strong>bold</strong> and this is <em>italic</em> and <s>strikethrough</s> Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet. Shortbread ice cream gingerbread cake cheesecake donut muffin cupcake. Wafer sweet shortbread tiramisu cotton candy cake I love jujubes cheesecake. Oat cake shortbread jujubes gummies croissant ice cream. Gummies dragée jujubes gummies liquorice apple pie. Jelly-o I love bonbon muffin sugar plum I love. Pudding cheesecake oat cake halvah tiramisu tootsie roll I love brownie. Liquorice gingerbread cupcake toffee marshmallow sweet lemon drops. Cupcake carrot cake bear claw muffin wafer gummi bears halvah. Sweet fruitcake liquorice halvah sweet. Pastry cupcake I love cheesecake croissant liquorice cotton candy. Jelly-o chocolate candy canes I love fruitcake tart I love carrot cake. Candy I love cupcake chocolate bar oat cake I love. Sugar plum shortbread tart pie pastry.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wheres your html?

Comment: @Crystal forgot to add it, fixed it already!! full code is there

Comment: Please read about [Runnable Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) so we can see how it looks currently

Comment: @Fork done! is it working now?

Comment: @suibaiter Yep. By thumb do you mean the image (thumbnail) or the small scrollbar inside the image?

Comment: @Fork the scrollbar thumb! the little red thing that overflows, i want it to stay inside the border. i also wanted to change the shape to one thats custom made but i have a better knowledge on how to do that, for now my priority is being able to go up without it leaving the borders

Comment: @Fork i run your code. "priority is being able to go up without it leaving the borders". your codes seems like its working. the page will scroll more once theres no content to scroll inside your thumb. whats your real goal??

Comment: @Crystal Apologies but I am not the one you should be asking, I am not OP

Comment: sorry about that. i mean @suibaiter  i run your code. "priority is being able to go up without it leaving the borders". your codes seems like its working. the page will scroll more once theres no content to scroll inside your thumb. whats your real goal??

Comment: @Crystal i dont quite understand what you mean. by thumb i mean the red scrollbar thing from the scrollbox that appears when picture is hovered. whenever i scroll, especially up, the red thing overlaps the black border that i set for that scrollbox since it has uneven borders. i want it to stay inside the box at all times

Comment: @suibater i see what you mean let me pull some code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this is what you mean about your scrollbar thumb.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: gothicpixel;
  src: url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/69gsw1ubmz94bh2/DoubleHomicide.ttf);
}

#cont {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/657655298613575691/853068735812206612/lace-border-png-37013.png") 60 fill round;
  border-radius: 0px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  filter: drop-shadow(.7px .5px 1px white) drop-shadow(.7px .5px 1px white);
}

.imgbg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

#float {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: gothicpixel;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: regular;
  color: #aa0000;
  text-shadow: -.9px 0 #fff, 0 .9px #fff, .9px 0 #fff, 0 -.9px #fff, 0 0;
  animation-name: floating;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes floating {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0, 15px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -0px);
  }
}

#scroll {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 4%;
  width: 250px;
  top: 140px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 255px 15px 225px 15px/15px 225px 15px 255px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: #FFFFFF90;
  transition: opacity .35s ease;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: wow;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #aa0000;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#cont:hover #scroll {
  opacity: 1;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 35%, black 165%);
}

#cont:hover #overlay {
  width: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 1%, black 199%, black 150%, black 100%, black 75%, black 50%, black 25%, gray 200%);
  transition: background 4s ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 1, 1, 1);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border:4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  background-color: red;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">

  <img class=imgbg src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/940072943424270426/994052217600487524/mana_birra.jpg">
  <div id="float"> tomy </div>
  <div id="overlay"> </div>
  <div id="scroll"> hi this is <strong>bold</strong> and this is <em>italic</em> and <s>strikethrough</s> Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet. Shortbread ice cream gingerbread cake cheesecake donut muffin cupcake. Wafer sweet shortbread tiramisu cotton candy cake I love jujubes cheesecake. Oat cake shortbread jujubes gummies croissant ice cream. Gummies dragée jujubes gummies liquorice apple pie. Jelly-o I love bonbon muffin sugar plum I love. Pudding cheesecake oat cake halvah tiramisu tootsie roll I love brownie. Liquorice gingerbread cupcake toffee marshmallow sweet lemon drops. Cupcake carrot cake bear claw muffin wafer gummi bears halvah. Sweet fruitcake liquorice halvah sweet. Pastry cupcake I love cheesecake croissant liquorice cotton candy. Jelly-o chocolate candy canes I love fruitcake tart I love carrot cake. Candy I love cupcake chocolate bar oat cake I love. Sugar plum shortbread tart pie pastry.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I know what he means, you know the scrollbar that shows when you hover over the absolute div? He wants to align that small scrollbar to the border rather than the scrollbar being rendered inside the block. Good example would be a `fieldset` tag with a `legend`. Basically the `legend` in this case would be the small scrollbar. [HTML Fieldset](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset)

Comment: hmmm. let see what he says noticed the difference between the scrollbars, his cover the border and code i provide doesnt cover the border, which i believe what he says on his comment above. "the red thing overlaps the black border that i set for that scrollbox since it has uneven borders. i want it to stay inside the box at all times"

Comment: @Crystal i was looking to change the scrollbar that appears when hovered, this solution does work though, so no worries!

Comment: @Crystal if you know of a way to get the scrollbar to be rendered inside the box then please let me know though since its probably gonna help with another thing i was hoping to do!!

Comment: @suibaiter what type of rendering your want? like follow the border however shape it is? Let me know

Comment: @Crystal well, i was thinking smth like the scrollbar staying on the side (as it would usually do) and scrolling all the way up, but when it hits a corner, it goes under it (basically since the box corners r uneven, a piece of the scrollbar disappears and goes "under" it)